# Disable logging of DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

Due to external circumstances, my application could run into a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` when updating data in the database and then calling `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`. I'm handling this exception for myself by `catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)` and then reacting to this error case. Hence this error should not be handled or logged by Entity Framework.

Unfortunately, EF seems to log the error internally *before* my exception handler can jump in. I tried to configure the DbContext logging in Startup.cs as follows in order to prevent logging the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, but it did not help:

```
services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
{
    options
        .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
        .LogTo(_ => { }, new[] { CoreEventId.OptimisticConcurrencyException });
});
```

Obviously when `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is thrown, it does not get the `CoreEventId.OptimisticConcurrencyException` event ID and hence cannot be filtered with it. Is there another way how to disable logging of the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`?

Comment: Logging where? EF Core isn't logging anything by itself. `LogTo` is the simplified logging mechanism used mainly to dump queries. Are you referring to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging? You can configure the logging level per category in that case. The `appsettings.json` file specifies the logging level for various categories. You can also [specify the logging level per event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3#changing-the-log-level-for-an-event) with `ConfigureWarnings`

Comment: In `appsettings.json` the logging level for the `Microsoft` category is Warning: `"Microsoft": "Warning",`. You can specify a different level for EF Core, the Update category in it or specifically `CoreEventId.OptimisticConcurrencyException`, whose category is probably `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.OptimisticConcurrencyException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is not covered by the `CoreEventId.OptimisticConcurrencyException`, but gets the basic event ID 10000. Hence it can be handled in the `.LogTo()` method only by this event ID.

Since I'm using NLog, I decided to go another way and disable the specific logger in *nlog.config*: `<logger name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update" minlevel="Error" final="true" />`

Answer (score 1):

You you can conditionally log events based on the LogLevel and eventId, eg

```
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=EfCore7Test;TrustServerCertificate=true;Integrated Security=true",
        o =>
        {
            o.UseRelationalNulls();
        })
        .LogTo(m => Console.WriteLine(m), (eventId,logLevel) =>
        {
            //Console.WriteLine($"{eventId.Name} {eventId.Id}");
            if (logLevel >= LogLevel.Debug && eventId.Id != 10006) //Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.OptimisticConcurrencyException
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        );
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, unfortunately it does not help in terms of the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75618171/disable-logging-of-dbupdateconcurrencyexception/75618693?noredirect=1#comment133417697_75618693

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what logging is used but it can't be `LogTo`. The way this method is written, nothing should be logged, no matter what. The `categories` argument is used to filter all events. Those that match are passed to the `action` delegate which logs nothing in this case `_ =>{}`

I suspect the application uses `Microft.Extensions.Logging`. Filtering in this case is explained in the [EF Core Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3) page.

One way is to [suppress logging a specific event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3#suppress-logging-an-event) :

```
options
 .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
 .ConfigureWarnings(b => b.Ignore(CoreEventId.OptimisticConcurrencyException));
```

Another is to change the logging level for that event :

```
.ConfigureWarnings(
    b => b.Log(
            (CoreEventId.OptimisticConcurrencyException, LogLevel.Information)));
```

The `appsettings.json` generated by most project templates logs only `Warning` messages and above for the `Microsoft` category, so switching that event to `Information` should exclude it.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Another option is to configure how that category or event are handled by [the logging infrastructure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#how-filtering-rules-are-applied), eg by changing the logging level for the category, excluding the event or logging it to a different provider.

Comment: My problem is that when `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is thrown, it seems not to get the `CoreEventId.OptimisticConcurrencyException`. I've extended the logging and the event ID for `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` seems to be the base event ID 10000 and the event name is _Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.SaveChangesFailed_. I'm now trying to figure out how to filter this specific exception (?).

Comment: @Matthias filter from where? .NET's ILogger? Serilog? Some other logging library? How was logging configured in the first place?

Comment: I was hoping for a general solution, independent of the concrete logger implementation. In my current case it's NLog.

Comment: The only thing that _seems_ to work is to configure NLog as follows, but of course it does not only discard the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, but also other exceptions from the _Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update_ logger: `<logger name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update" minlevel="Error" final="true" />`

Answer (score 1):

I posted an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30429) about it and say it's a bug and there's a PR out to fix it.  I think once it's done your code should work.